# Combine 3 arrays of objects into one and Randomize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the lastFM api with this plugin. https://github.com/fxb/javascript-last.fm-api

I have a for loop that calls the "makeList" function 3 times based on an array of lastfm users.

```
var makeList = function( num ) {
    // query using last fm api 
    // spits out an array of 3 objects
}

for ( var i = 0; i < 3; i ++ ){
   makeList( i );
}
```

My questions:
1) How can I consolidate these arrays into 1 array with 9 objects 
2) Can I randomize the items in the array?

[image: From console.log]

Comment: [Concat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp) and [Randomize](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array)

Comment: @NaNpx You should put that in an answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `array.concat` to combine your arrays, and a custom `sort` function to randomize the order of the items in that array.

```
var arr1 = [
    { name: 'Alan' },
    { name: 'Barney' },
    { name: 'Cassius' }
];

var arr2 = [
    { name: 'Derek' },
    { name: 'Eric' },
    { name: 'Fred' }
];

var arr3 = [
    { name: 'Graham' },
    { name: 'Howard' },
    { name: 'Isaac' }
];

// Now I am one big array
var bigArray = arr1.concat(arr2, arr3);

// Now my member objects are randomized
bigArray.sort(function() {
    return 0.5 - Math.random();
});
```